# The reason for displaying the "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'length' of undefined" error is in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code I used in the browser will error
In fact, I need to send 2 parameters as Ajax when clicking on the image

```js
function sendrate(rated, rid) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  
  xmlhttp.open('get', 'gethint.php?q=' + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<img value="1" rid="3" onclick="sendrate(this.value, this.rid)" src="./images/rate1.jpg" alt="rate1" height="20" width="20">
```

Comment: You haven't defined `str` so you cannot read its length.

Comment: It means that `str` is `undefined`.

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory...  `str` var is `undefined`.

Comment: instead of `this.value`, you need to fetch `this.getAttribute("value")`. image doesn't have a `value` property unless set explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img` doesn't have a value property unless set explicitly, use `getAttribute` instead and pass `this` instead of the attributes themselves.

```
function sendrate( thisObj ) {
      var str = thisObj.getAttribute( "value" );
      var rid = thisObj.getAttribute( "rid" );
      //rest of the code
}
```

and

```
<img value="1" rid="3" onclick="sendrate(this)" src="./images/rate1.jpg" alt="rate1" height="20" width="20">
```

**Demo**

```js
function sendrate( thisObj ) {
  var str = thisObj.getAttribute( "value" );
  var rid = thisObj.getAttribute( "rid" );
  console.log( "values correctly fetched as", str, rid );
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  
  xmlhttp.open('get', 'gethint.php?q=' + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<img value="1" rid="3" onclick="sendrate(this)" src="./images/rate1.jpg" alt="rate1" height="20" width="20">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
When I used your code, I made this mistake
Uncaught ReferenceError: thisObj is not defined

Comment: You need to pass `thisObj` as a parameter of `sendrate()` as described in the answer:

`function sendrate(thisObj) {...}`

Comment: Did you also made the changes to image tag?

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for `str`:

```
str = str || "";
if (str.length == 0) { ...}
```

Comment: Rather than doing this, I would try to understand *why* `str` is undefined.